# What is DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST flag?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand this flag DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 but not able to figure it out. How does it effect pushing images and pulling images, let's say from docker hub?

Comment: Did you read the official doc? [Content trust in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/security/trust/content_trust/)

Comment: See also https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13987/how-to-pin-public-root-key-when-downloading-an-image-with-docker-pull-docker-co/13988#13988

Answer (score 2):

DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 this is env variable to enable Docker content trust by default it is in disable mode.

read more about DCT in official docs [DCT docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/security/trust/content_trust/)

For specific  build/push/pull you can use as docker command line flag as well

--disable-content-trust=false or --disable-content-trust=true